# Linux/Kernel: How to select Videobuf2 framework as kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-11.04, kernel-module

I'd like to select videobuf2 modules as kernel modules. I do "make menuconfig" but I don't find anything.

I'd like to have .ko files in order to load them because I'm programming a driver based on VIVI which uses them.

I guess, I'll have to recompile the kernel entirely, but is it possible just to recompile/rebuild the modules part?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with 3.1.10 kernel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: you need to install a device which uses Videobuf2 framework, hence, videobuf2-core.ko and so on are automatically installed. 
In my case I selected "Virtual Driver" as kernel module and I think this did the trick.

From Pawel Osciak: It's actually intentional. You wouldn't want to compile videobuf2
unless you wanted to compile a driver that uses it, so vb2 is selected
automatically when you select a driver to be compiled. You can't
select it manually in menuconfig (unless you edit the config file).